# how to map complex type in Attribute with jsonapi 1.0

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a class `SubscriptionType` and in its attribute is a complex class called `InfoText`, `LongInfoText` and `Name` they all have `en` and `ur` property.
when i use `JsonApiNet 3.0.0` library to deserialize my json from a wep api. all objects are retrieved expect the complex type that exists in attributes. null values are shown.
I have tried to use my own resolver but it didn't not work. can someone help me in this. Thank you

**My resolver**

```
 public class NamingThingsIsHardResolver : JsonApiPropertyResolver
    {
        public override PropertyInfo ResolveJsonApiAttribute(Type type, string attributeName)
        {
            if (type == typeof(SubscriptionType) && attributeName == "name")
            {
                return type.GetProperty("Name");
            }

            return base.ResolveJsonApiAttribute(type, attributeName);
        }
    }
```

**my type**

```
public class Subscription
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public SubscriptionType SubscriptionType { get; set; }
}
    public class SubscriptionType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }      
    public string BusinessModelType { get; set; }
    public InfoText InfoText;
    public string LineType { get; set; }
    public LongInfoText LongInfoText;
     //[JsonApiRelationship("name")] // [JsonApiAttribute("name")] //also not working
    public string Name;
}
```

**my complex type**

```
public class Name 
{ 
    public string En { get; set; } 
    public string Ur { get; set; } 
}

 public class InfoText
    {
        public string En { get; set; }
        public string Ur { get; set; }
    }

 public class LongInfoText
    {
        public string En { get; set; }
        public string Ur { get; set; }
    }
```

**my json**
this json is simplified. some attributes and relationships are removed

```
 {
    "data": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "contract-id": "103",
                "payment-type": "prepaid",
                "status": "active",
            },
            "id": "103",
            "links": {
                "self": "/api/v1/subscriptions/103"
            },
            "relationships": {              
                "subscription-type": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "subscription-types"
                    },
                    "links": {
                        "related": "/api/v1/subscriptions/103/subscription-type"
                    }
                }
                
            },
            "type": "subscriptions"
        }
    ],
    "included": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "business-model-type": "prepaid",
                "info-text": {
                    "en": null,
                    "ur": null
                },
                "line-type": "mobile",
                "long-info-text": {
                    "en": null,
                    "ur": null
                },
                "name": {
                    "en": "Start prepaid",
                    "ur": "Start Prepaid"
                }
            },
            "id": "1",
            "links": {
                "self": "/api/v1/subscription-types/1"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "billing-rate-plans": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": "/api/v1/subscription-types/1/billing-rate-plans"
                    }
                }
            },
            "type": "subscription-types"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnot find solution in JsonApiNet library, so i created a json deserializer like below. i am not happy with it but it works. please do improve this answer thanks.

my method in SubscriptionType.cs

```
 public void InjectAttributes(JsonApiAttributes attributes) {

            // InfoText
            var infoText = attributes["info-text"].ToString();
            InfoText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lang>(infoText);

            // LongInfoText
            var longInfoText = attributes["long-info-text"].ToString();
            LongInfoText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lang>(longInfoText);

            // Name
            var name = attributes["name"].ToString();
            Name = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lang>(name);

        }
```

and i called it like this.

```
var document = JsonApi.Document<List<Subscription>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

List<Subscription> subscriptions = document.Resource;

foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
{
    subscription.SubscriptionType.InjectAttributes(document.Included[0].Attributes);
}
```

a separate c# object class is also created

```
public class Lang
    {
        public string En { get; set; }
        public string Ur { get; set; }
    }
```